# RenderComponentAsync vs html? prerender blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

```
<div id="Counter">
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(new { IncrementAmount = 10 }))
</div>
```

why would i use this when i can just use

```
<counter IncrementAmount="10"/>
```

"When the page or view is rendered, components are **prerendered** at the **same time**."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code sample you’ve quoted is used when you want to include a Blazor component into a MVC view or a Razor page. If you’re just writing a standard Blazor app then you wouldn’t need this syntax.

When using this syntax the component is going to be prerendered on the server and will become interactive once a SignalR connection has been established with the client browser.